# Unable to create as required dataframe in r

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, dataframe, apply

I'm reading text from OCR'd pdf and extracting values from it so as to create a dataframe out of it.
But the dataframe created doesn't meet my requirement, here is the code I tried to create read and extract file and create a dataframe

```
    library(pdftools)
library(tesseract)
library(stringi)
library(TraMineRextras)
All_files=Sys.glob("*.pdf")
df <- data.frame()
Words <- Page <- TEXT <- Status <-   c()

chk_words=c("swimming pool","gym","school","para")
for (i in 1:length(All_files)){
  file_name <- All_files[i]

  cnt <- pdf_info(All_files[i])$pages
  for(j in 1:cnt)
  {
    img_file <- pdftools::pdf_convert(All_files[i], format = 'tiff', pages = j, dpi = 400)
    text <- ocr(img_file)
    ocr_text <- capture.output(cat(text))
    check=sapply(ocr_text, paste0, collapse="")
    #junk <- dir(path="D:/All_PDF_Files", pattern="tiff")
    #file.remove(junk)
   for(k in chk_words)
      {
      br=if(length(which(stri_detect_fixed(tolower(check),tolower(k)))) <= 0){ print("Not Present") } else {print("Present")}
      if(br=="Present")
        {
           Words[i] = k
           Page[i] = j
           TEXT[i] = check  
           Status[i] = br
        }
      }
    }
  df=rbind(df, cbind(file_name, Status, Page, Words, TEXT))
}
```

This gives me dataframe only for one word.

This is what I get

```
fileName   Status   page   words              TEXT
test.pdf   Present  2      swimming pool      KU L Trevnano
test1.pdf  Present  2      swimming pool      KU L Trevnano
test1.pdf  Present  6      swimming pool      L
```

but this is what I expect

```
fileName   Status        Page             Words                    TEXT
test.pdf   Present        1             gym            I go gym and school regularly 
test.pdf   Present        1             school         I go gym and school regularly
test.pdf   Present        3             school     Here is the next school
test1.pdf  Present        4            swimming pool  In swimming pool
test1.pdf  Present        7            gym         next to Gold gym
test2.pdf  Not Present    -               -          -
```

**fileName**=Name of the File

**Status**=If any word is found then "Present" else "Not Present"

**Page**=Here "1", "3" defines the page number on which the word was found;; on page "1" word "gym" was found and on page "3" word "school" was found.

**Words**= Which all words were found ;; like only "gym" and "school" were found on page 1 and 3 of test.pdf file AND only "swimming pool" and "gym" were found on page 4 and 7 of test1.pdf file.

**TEXT** = It is the text in which the word was found

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Thanks

P.S : access to sample files https://spaces.hightail.com/space/zWlgzO0Tzu

Comment: You should really pare this back to a *much* smaller problem showing the result you get after doing all the OCR, the code you use to process it, your current result, and then the result you want. As it is, downloading sample files, installing extra libraries, and debugging code including absolute paths (D:\), seems like a lot of work to just answer an SO question. The easier you make it for potential answerers, the quicker you'll get an answer.

Comment: Updated the O/P I get and as of now no need to include absolute path(that was for deleting .tiff files), but so as to know others what I have coded ,that's why I have included entire code.

Comment: @thelatemail any suggestions on where I'm going wrong